# Request for Vimeo embedding

Tags: feature-request

I am wondering if we can add Vimeo embedding on this site. Since it is an Audio *Video* production site, it makes sense to have embedded videos. Since [Youtube embedding is supported](https://video.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190/youtube-and-soundcloud-embedding-is-now-enabled/191#191), can we add Vimeo support as well?

Comment: +1 This could help us widen the visibility of the site - I have some clients who ban Youtube but allow Vimeo (yes, I don't know why either)

Comment: +1 vital. Vimeo is a far more professional platform (particularly with their PRO user level) and will help illustrate questions without people having to leave the site.